# jquery how to set values from input field to other element data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is what I've got:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li data-order=""><input class="cant-see-me" value="3" /></li>
<li data-order=""><input class="cant-see-me" value="1" /></li>
<li data-order=""><input class="cant-see-me" value="2" /></li>
</ul>
```

I need this:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li data-order="3"><input class="cant-see-me" value="3" /></li>
<li data-order="1"><input class="cant-see-me" value="1" /></li>
<li data-order="2"><input class="cant-see-me" value="2" /></li>
</ul>
```

I'd need to populate data-order values with ones found in input field.
I've tried with each function, but all I've got was value from first input field "3" to be inserted into data-order.

this is what I've tried + many variations of it

```
$.each($('.sortable li'), function (index, value) { 
/*  $('.sortable li').each(function() {  this one had the same result*/

  var bla = $('.cant-see-me').val();
  $(this).attr('data-order', (bla));

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're trying to do it is getting every element with the 'cant-see-me' class. This would return back an array of 3 input elements according to the HTML. You need to get the value of the 'cant-see-me' class belonging to each individual `<li>` element:

```
var bla = $($(this).find('.cant-see-me')).val();
$(this).attr('data-order', bla);
```